# Placing rooks on a $5\times 5$ board

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there of placing 5 nontaken rooks on 5*5 board ?
a)how many ways if none lie  on the main diagonal?
b) How many ways if exactly one lies on the main diagonal?

Comment: What are "nontaken" rooks? Not attacking eachother?

Comment: yea,non attacking

Answer (score 2):

First notice that there is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between the set of $n$ non-attacking rooks on a $n \times n$ chessboard and the permutations of a set of $n$ elements. You can generate any configuration of $n$ non-attacking rooks by first placing them on the main diagonal and then permute the rows.

So the total number of configuration for placing $n$ non-attacking rooks on a $n \times n$ chessboard is $n!$.

To place $n$ non-attacking rooks on a $n \times n$ chessboard avoiding the main diagonal,
we can

- Start with all possible configurations of placing $n$ non-attacking rooks on a $n \times n$ chessboard. There are $n!$ of this.
- Subtract away $n$ times those number of configuration where the upper-left corner is occupied. There are $n \times (n-1)!$ configurations to kill.
- This will get rid of all configurations with at least one rooks are on the diagonals. However, for those configuration with at least two rooks on the main diagonal. Above will be an overall kill. You need to add them back. There are $\binom{n}{2} \times (n-2)!$ to add back.
- Now those configuration with at least three rooks on the main diagonal will be over counted. We need to subtract them away. In general, we need to repeat this subtraction/add back cycle until all cases are covered.

As a result, the total number of configuration for placing $n$ non-attacking rooks on a $n \times n$ chessboard avoiding the main diagonal is given by

$$!n = n! - \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}(n-k)! = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\tag{*1}$$

Back to our original problem. For the particular case $n = 5$, above formula tell us

$$\bbox[5pt,border:1px solid black]{
\text{ the answer of } (a) \text{ is }\;\; !5 = 44
}$$

For part $(b)$, there are $5$ slots on the main diagonal for us to place the first rook. The number of ways of placing the remaining four rooks is the same as the one placing $4$ non-attacking rooks on a $4 \times 4$ chessboard avoiding the main diagonal. This means

$$\bbox[5pt,border:1px solid black]{
\text{ the answer of } (b) \text{ is }\;\; 5 \times !4 = 45
}$$

In the above analysis, the way of counting by alternate subtracting and adding configurations back is called [Inclusion Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). It is a very power tool to deal with this sort of problem.

The sort of permutation such that none of the elements appear in their original position
is called [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). The numbers of derangement of $n$ objects is given by the subfactorial function $!n$ in $(*1)$. Look at
the wiki page of derangement or the one on 
[mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html)
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The ways of taking 5 out of 25 is counted by $ 25 \choose 5$=$\frac{25!}{5!(25-5)!}$. Each arrangement of 5 chips placed on a 5$\times$ 5 board is counted exactly once.

a) if none lie in the main diagonal, then there are only 20 boxes left to choose so it is counted by $20 \choose 5$.
b) If exactly one lies on the main diagonal then you have to place the 4 chips left on the 20 non-diagonal boxes. But there are 5 ways of placing one chip on the diagonal then there are 5$\times$ $20 \choose 5$.

Comment: This would be correct if we were talking about arbitrary tokens placed on a chessboard, but this analysis doesn't take into account the 'nonattacking' element of the question.

Comment: haha.. 'non taken' = 'nonattacking'?

Answer (score -1):

There is a rook on each column. On an $n \times n$ board, you have $n$ options for the rook on the first column, that leaves $n - 1$ for the second column, ... In all there are $n!$ positions. Taking away the diagonal for all/some can be handled in a similar way. If there are exactly $k$ on the diagonal, this in essence takes away $k$ rooks and $k$ rows, giving $(n - k)!$, as you can select $k$ of the columns in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, in total:
$$
(n - k)! \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!}
$$

Comment: This is for ones when no one on main diagonal?
So we need to substruct 5  places (main diagonal)?

Comment: @user147866, it covers both cases, somewhat generalized.